# Static Private IPv6 Address SLAAC RFC 7217 on Windows 11

Tags: networking, ip, windows-11, ipv6

I have a LTE ISP that give me a /64 IPv6 prefix that changes every 4 hours. I would like to set a Static SLAAC suffix in order to set Firewall rules on the router using negative netmask. I read online that Windows 11 should implement RFC 7217, so it should be possible to get a static SLAAC suffix without exposing MAC address. The problem is that is not working.

If i set RandomizeIdentifiers to Disabled, i get a static suffix based on my MAC address (this is not safe due to host tracking). If I set RandomizeIdentifiers to Enabled, i get a randomized suffix that change every reboot, or interface restart.
Most modern operating systems already implement this since years.

Is there something I need to change in windows settings? Is there another way to get a static SLAAC suffix without exposing MAC address?